# Reading multiple records related to every record in the result set at a time

Tags: sql-server, union, sap-ase, sql-cte

I have 3 tables:

- **`Message` table** having `MsgID`, `MsgText`, `MsgDate` columns. `MsgId` is PK.
- **`MessageSender`** table having `MsgId`, `SenderId`, `SenderName`. `MsgId` is FK.
- **`MessageTo`** table having `MsgId`, `ToId`, `ToName`. `MsgId` is FK.

Every Message will have **one Sender**. But it can have **many Recipients**. i.e. For every record in the `Message` table, there will be one record in `MessageSender` table and **more than one records** in the `MessageTo` table.

**I want to get ALL details of the all Messages *in one query or at a time***. e.g. for a specific Message, who is the Sender and who ALL are recipients.

How can I do this?

I am using MSSQL Server 2005 and Sybase 15.

Note: I have given only relevant details of the tables here. And I cannot change table schema since it's been there in production for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct M.MsgID, M.MsgText, MS.SenderID, MS.SenderName, 
MT.ToName, MT.ToId 
from Message M, MessageSender MS, MessageTo MT
where M.MessageID = MS.MessageID and 
M.MessageID = MT.MessageID 
and MsgDate like '%20130307%' -- To get the messages sent on 07-Mar-2013
```